# Local Django website won't load in browser

Tags: django, centos, localhost, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm guessing there's a very simple solution to this, but I searched every forum and setup guide and can't figure it out:

I built a Django/CentOS-6.3 environment on my *local* server (using VirtualBox and Vagrant). When I startup my server in the vagrant terminal with 'python manage.py runserver [::]:8000' it starts up with no errors.

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
May 31, 2013 - 13:56:15
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'mysitename.settings'
Development server is running at http://[::]:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However, when I try to navigate to '`http://127.0.0.1:8001`' in my browser (I set up port forwarding from port 8000 to port 8001 in my Vagrantfile), the browser just hangs for 5 minutes until it times out, then it returns the message:

```
> The connection was reset 
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. 
> ...
```

This is the exact same message I get from the browser even after I shut down my local server. My computer obviously recognizes this as a forwarded port, because any other port I try (such as 8000) instantly returns an error saying that it can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.

With regard to the server files, I have done many similar setups with Django/Ubuntu in the past and have never had any issues, but there must be something different about Django/CentOS that is causing this to happen (or maybe I made a mistake someone in one of my server files). I have followed guides for setting up Django & PostgreSQL on CentOS, too, but to no avail. I'll comment some of the files I have created/edited below.

If anyone has a solution, or even has advice on where to *start* looking for errors, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Here are the server files I checked/edited, along with some tests that I've done, which can hopefully help shed light on the reason for the current issue:

 - 'django.wsgi' (in dir above project)
 - '/etc/httpd/conf.d' (contains 'wsgi.conf')
 - Tested 'import django' in python terminal
 - restarted apache and vagrant
 - Created the file '/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf' and added the line WSGIScriptAlias
 - Added to these 8 lines to '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf': (docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration)
 - Restarted Apache and MySQL

Comment: what happens when you do `python manage.py runserver [::]:8001` ?

Comment: That doesn't work either - same result.

Comment: I'm writing this as an answer 'cause for some reason I can't comment. I have the EXACT same issue. Problem loading page on 127.0.0.1:8000 For me, however, the app runs on 0.0.0.0:8000.

Answer (score 6):

If your network is configured correctly and your django application with

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

and you still can't access your django app from the VM host there is almost certainly a firewall issue.  The solution above is good if you are running iptables.

I deployed CentOS 7 on a virtualbox VM from a Windows 7 host.  I didn't know that this distribution uses firewalld, not iptables to control access.

if

> ps -ae | grep firewall

returns something like

> 602 ?            00:00:00 firewalld

your system is running firewalld, not iptables.  They do not run together.

To correct you VM so you can access your django site from the host use the commands:

> firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent
>
> firewall-cmd --reload

Many thanks to pablo v for pointing this out in the post "Access django server on virtual Machine".

Answer (score 4):

the host's "127.0.0.1" is not the same as the guest's "127.0.0.1". Per default the command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

listens only to the guest's localhost. You should be able to test it from within the vm (use "vagrant ssh" to login) and run

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

The host as a different IP. To access the development server from the host you have to start it without ip restriction:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Yes:

```
python manage.py runserver [::]:8000
```

should be the same. But that's IPv6 syntax AFAIK. Are you sure that the "manage.py runserver" command supports IPv6 by default? I've never used ipv6 addresses w/ django, but looking at the source (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py) there seams to be a flag that the default to False ("--ipv6"). Perhaps that's the "real" problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

For a similar problem,

This command worked like a charm for me

```
python manage.py runserver [::]:8001
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your iptables, and stop it. Ubuntu commonly does not open the iptables when it starts.